# how to create an xml api that will give data to my android app

Tags: android, xml, parsing

well i have an android app that needs to be updated with data...
i know what to do on android-end for xml parsing...
but when i try to parse the data through the follwing xml file(a) using stringbuilder(b) i am not getting data in my app...

(a)data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document version="first">
<stuff code="firststuff">
<item1 build="first">This is first item.</item1>
<item2 build="second">This is second item.</item2>
<item3 build="third">This is third item.</item3>
</stuff>
<stuff code="secondtstuff">
<item1 build="first">This is first item.</item1>
<item2 build="second">This is second item.</item2>
<item3 build="third">This is third item.</item3>
</stuff>
<stuff code="thirdstuff">
<item1 build="first">This is first item.</item1>
<item2 build="second">This is second item.</item2>
<item3 build="third">This is third item.</item3>
</stuff>
</document>
```

(b) string that i use in my android app...

```
http://www.xyz.com/data.xml?build=second
```

java code below in 3 files (c)Main (d)HandlingXMLStuff (e)XMLDataCollected

(c)Main

```
package com.xyz.xmlpar1;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    static final String BaseURL="http://www.xyz.com/data.xml?code=";
    Button b;
    TextView tv;
    EditText et1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        et1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String item=et1.getText().toString();
        StringBuilder URL=new StringBuilder(BaseURL);
        URL.append(item);
        String fullURL=URL.toString();
        try{
            URL website=new URL(fullURL);
            SAXParserFactory spf=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp=spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr=sp.getXMLReader();
            HandlingXMLStuff doingWork=new HandlingXMLStuff();
            xr.setContentHandler(doingWork);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(website.openStream()));
            String information=doingWork.getInformation();
            tv.setText(information);

        }catch(Exception e){
            tv.setText("error");
        }


    }

}
```

(d)HandlingXMLStuff

```
package com.xyz.xmlpar1;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class HandlingXMLStuff extends DefaultHandler {

    XMLDataCollected info=new XMLDataCollected();

    public String getInformation(){
        return info.datatoString();
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(localName.equals("code")){
            String element=attributes.getValue("build");
            info.setData(element);
        }
    }

}
```

(e)XMLDataCollected

```
package com.xyz.xmlpar1;

public class XMLDataCollected {

    String datac=null;

    public void setData(String c){
        datac=c;
    }

    public String datatoString(){
        return datac;
    }

}
```

to fetch "second" data item..

where am i going wrong ???

Comment: We'll need to see the code you've written before we have much of a clue where you're going wrong. No crystal balls here.

Comment: sorry..i am updating question with the java code shortly...

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the tutorial that I posted on the duplicate of this question here: [Parsed XML data not retrieving in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417475/parsed-xml-data-not-retrieving-in-android/14418003#14418003)

Although that tutorial does not show getting attributes.

In short, your `startElement` should look something like this:

```
@Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

          if(localName.equals("stuff")){
            String element=attributes.getValue("code");
            info.setData(element); //element will hold "firststuff" on the first execution

        }
    }
```

You will need a separate `if` for each name you are trying to match.

Xml files in general are referred to like this (using your naming convention):

`<localName attributeName="attributeValue">textValue</localName>` So the `if` statement above will handle the lines `<stuff code="firststuff">` `<..."secondstuff">` etc. but you will have to add more to handle *each different* line.

I strongly suggest you follow a tutorial to get this accomplished, although, you will definitely learn a lot through trial and error.