# Parsed XML data not retrieving in android

Tags: android, xml, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to create an xml api that will give data to my android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416159/how-to-create-an-xml-api-that-will-give-data-to-my-android-app)

I have asked this previously too but this time I have done some research and came back as I didn't get any answer for my problem.

I have a data.xml file which has data that I want to give to my android app. I have done the android-end coding and I think its flawless. But the data is not being retrieved from the file into my app. My file structure goes this way:

(a)data.xml
(b)Main
(c)HandlingXMLStuff
(d)XMLDataCollected

(a)data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <document version="first">
    <stuff code="firststuff">
      <item1 build="first">This is first item.</item1>
      <item2 build="second">This is second item.</item2>
      <item3 build="third">This is third item.</item3>
    </stuff>
    <stuff code="secondtstuff">
      <item1 build="first">This is first item.</item1>
      <item2 build="second">This is second item.</item2>
      <item3 build="third">This is third item.</item3>
    </stuff>
    <stuff code="thirdstuff">
      <item1 build="first">This is first item.</item1>
      <item2 build="second">This is second item.</item2>
      <item3 build="third">This is third item.</item3>
    </stuff>
  </document>
```

(b)Main

```
package com.xyz.xmlpar1;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
  static final String BaseURL="http://www.xyz.com/data.xml?code=";
  Button b;
  TextView tv;
  EditText et1;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    et1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
  }
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
  }
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String item=et1.getText().toString();
    StringBuilder URL=new StringBuilder(BaseURL);
    URL.append(item);
    String fullURL=URL.toString();
    try{
      URL website=new URL(fullURL);
      SAXParserFactory spf=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
      SAXParser sp=spf.newSAXParser();
      XMLReader xr=sp.getXMLReader();
      HandlingXMLStuff doingWork=new HandlingXMLStuff();
      xr.setContentHandler(doingWork);
      xr.parse(new InputSource(website.openStream()));
      String information=doingWork.getInformation();
      tv.setText(information);
    }catch(Exception e){
      tv.setText("error");
    }
  }
}
```

(c)HandlingXMLStuff

```
package com.xyz.xmlpar1;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class HandlingXMLStuff extends DefaultHandler {
  XMLDataCollected info=new XMLDataCollected();
  public String getInformation(){
    return info.datatoString();
  }
  @Override
  public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
    Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(localName.equals("code")){
      String element=attributes.getValue("build");
      info.setData(element);
    }
  }
}
```

(d)XMLDataCollected

```
package com.xyz.xmlpar1;
public class XMLDataCollected {
  String datac=null;
  public void setData(String c){
    datac=c;
  }
  public String datatoString(){
    return datac;
  }
}
```

So when I type first or second or third it should retrieve the data. But it does not.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with your handler. You are only adding a `startElement` function, but really you need to at least deal with starting and ending a tag.

Also, your `localName.equals("code")` should actually look for the name of the tag i.e.`localName.equals("stuff")`

There is a full example here: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/11/android-parse-xml-file-example-using.html and plenty of posts here on http://stackoverflow.com to get you a fully working parser using SAX.

I would definitely suggest trying to debug your code to see what is actually happening when you run it. You can do this by using the debug mode in your IDE or by simply throwing some `System.out.println()` or `Log.d()` statements in there.

Comment: actually i am following tnb(buckys+mbb) tutorial...and the classes are exact duplicate of the code they used..also they have google weather api xml in there example...

Comment: Ok, so put a print statement inside your `startElement` function somewhere inside of the `if` statement you have there. Pretty sure it will never print. If not, you found your problem.

Comment: so what should i do in my code (actually in which java class file) to get the required output ??? 
and yes there was no output after using the print statement...